# how to do ffil on some columns using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

How to do `ffil` on some columns?
I don't need to `ffil` every columns, I would like to leave last columns.

[My input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIy0P.png) and [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n941f.png):

This code will `ffill` every columns and sheets. But I don't need to `ffill` the last columns of every sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/law.xlsx')

writer.sheet_names


excelfile = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/User/Desktop/law_out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
for i in writer.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, header=None)
    df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
    df.to_excel(excelfile, sheet_name=i, index=False)
excelfile.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no missing values but empty strings repalce them to missing values and chain with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select all columns without last:

```
import numpy as np

df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
```

Or if there are missing values:

```
df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].ffill()
```

instead:

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: what is np.nan - ? np == numpy?

Comment: @BoldGanbaatar - yes, added `import numpy as np`

Comment: df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].ffill()   this worked for me thank you Mr. jezrael

Comment: @BoldGanbaatar - thank you for patience ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?:

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2']:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: what is col? my sheets don't have names.

Comment: You need to access the columns you are after either by name or by location